# Warning while automatically creating unqiue constraints in Hibernate 6

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate 6.1.2 as implementation of JPA 3.1.0. In my persistence.xml, I have set

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

This makes my database being updated or created if necessary. (For final deployment, I am going to change this, but for now, it is supposed to work.)

During startup, I get warnings for unique constraints like

```
WARN: constraint "unique_constraint_name" of relation "table_name" does not exist, skipping
```

However, afterwards, the constraints do exist. So my theory is that some different part of the code misses them before hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto can create them.

I tried to read up on that, but I only found posts confirming that the update setting creates everything (including constraints) on demand, which is correct, but not exactly the answer to my questions:

1. Is my idea that some different part of the code is missing them before they can be created?
2. How can I change the code so that the warning is not needed?